# React project compile successfully can't view from the browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I did several react projects before but it is the first time I encountered this problem.

After I ran

```
npx create-react-app myapp
cd myapp
```

I created a react project, then I ran

```
npm start
```

It looks very fine:
[image: compile successfully]

However, the project did not show in the browser, when I go to the localhost:3000 it reminds me "This site can’t be reached":
[image]

I tried to change the port but no matter what I do, this situation still lasts. The environment is good, the computer is good, the nodejs is good, anyone has encountered this kind of situation before can give me some advice? Thanks!